# BindingList<> (master) with a composed BindingList<> (child) reference

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, poco, xtragrid

I have a situation where a BindingList<> represents a collection of POCOs that have sub-collections of similar nature, Here is a sample code of two such POCOs and their respective lists:

The `DirectoryTypePoco`

```
  public class DirectoryTypePoco : IBasePoco
  {

    public DirectoryTypePoco()
    {

    }

    public DirectoryTypePoco(Int16 directoryTypeId, String directoryImplementation, String directoryDescription, DirectoryDefinitionPocoList directoryDefinition)
    {
      DirectoryTypeId = directoryTypeId;
      DirectoryImplementation = directoryImplementation;
      DirectoryDescription = directoryDescription;
      DirectoryDefinition = directoryDefinition;
    }

    public Int16 DirectoryTypeId { get; set; }
    public String DirectoryImplementation { get; set; }
    public String DirectoryDescription { get; set; }
    public DirectoryDefinitionPocoList DirectoryDefinition { get; set; }

    public object GenerateEntity(GenericRepository repository, params object[] parameters)
    {
      var lastMaxEntityId = repository.GetQuery<DirectoryType>().Select(select => @select.DirectoryTypeId).DefaultIfEmpty().Max();

      var newEntity = new DirectoryType
      {
        DirectoryTypeId = (short)(lastMaxEntityId + 1),
        DirectoryImplementation = this.DirectoryImplementation,
        DirectoryDescription = this.DirectoryDescription
      };

      return newEntity;
    }

  }
```

And the `BindingList<DirectoryTypePoco>`:

```
  public class DirectoryTypePocoList : BindingList<DirectoryTypePoco>
  {

    public DirectoryTypePocoList()
    {
      using (var repository = new GenericRepository(new PWRDbContext()))
      {
        var query = repository.GetQuery<DirectoryType>();

        foreach (var r in query)
        {
          Add(new DirectoryTypePoco(r.DirectoryTypeId, r.DirectoryImplementation, r.DirectoryDescription, new DirectoryDefinitionPocoList(r.DirectoryTypeId)));
        }
      }
    }

    public DirectoryTypePocoList(short directoryTypeId)
    {
      using (var repository = new GenericRepository(new PWRDbContext()))
      {
        var query = repository.GetQuery<DirectoryType>(where => where.DirectoryTypeId == directoryTypeId);

        foreach (var r in query)
        {
          Add(new DirectoryTypePoco(r.DirectoryTypeId, r.DirectoryImplementation, r.DirectoryDescription, new DirectoryDefinitionPocoList(r.DirectoryTypeId)));
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The second object: `DirectoryDefinitionPoco`

```
  public class DirectoryDefinitionPoco : IBasePoco
  {

    public DirectoryDefinitionPoco()
    {

    }

    public DirectoryDefinitionPoco(Int16 directoryTypeId, Byte parameterId, String parameterName, String parameterValidation, Boolean encryptionRequired, PocoChangeType changeType = PocoChangeType.None)
    {
      DirectoryTypeId = directoryTypeId;
      ParameterId = parameterId;
      ParameterName = parameterName;
      ParameterDescription = parameterName;
      ParameterRequired = false;
      ParameterValidation = parameterValidation;
      EncryptionRequired = encryptionRequired;
    }

    public Int16 DirectoryTypeId { get; set; }
    public Byte ParameterId { get; set; }
    public String ParameterName { get; set; }
    public String ParameterDescription { get; set; }
    public String ParameterValidation { get; set; }
    public Boolean ParameterRequired { get; set; }
    public Boolean EncryptionRequired { get; set; }    

    public object GenerateEntity(GenericRepository repository, params object[] parameters)
    {
      var masterId = (short) parameters[0];
      var lastMaxEntityId = repository.GetQuery<DirectoryDefinition>(where => where.DirectoryTypeId == masterId).Select(select => @select.ParameterId).DefaultIfEmpty().Max();

      var newEntity = new DirectoryDefinition
      {
        DirectoryTypeId = (short)parameters[0],
        ParameterId = (byte)(lastMaxEntityId + 1),
        ParameterName = this.ParameterName,
        ParameterDescription = this.ParameterDescription,
        ParameterValidation = this.ParameterValidation,
        ParameterRequired = this.ParameterRequired,
        EncryptionRequired = this.EncryptionRequired
      };

      return newEntity;
    }
  }
```

And `BindingList<DirectoryDefinitionPoco>`:

```
  public class DirectoryDefinitionPocoList : BindingList<DirectoryDefinitionPoco>
  {
    public DirectoryDefinitionPocoList(short directoryTypeId)
    {
      using (var repository = new GenericRepository(new PWRDbContext()))
      {
        var query = repository.GetQuery<DirectoryDefinition>(where => where.DirectoryTypeId == directoryTypeId);

        foreach (var r in query)
        {
          Add(new DirectoryDefinitionPoco(r.DirectoryTypeId, r.ParameterId, r.ParameterName, r.ParameterValidation, r.EncryptionRequired));
        }
      }
    }

    public List<DirectoryDefinition> GetSourceQuery()
    {
      List<DirectoryDefinition> result;

      using (var repository = new GenericRepository(new PWRDbContext()))
      {
        result =  repository.GetQuery<DirectoryDefinition>().ToList();
      }

      return result;
    }

    public List<DirectoryDefinition> GetSourceQuery(short directoryTypeId)
    {
      List<DirectoryDefinition> result;

      using (var repository = new GenericRepository(new PWRDbContext()))
      {
        result = repository.GetQuery<DirectoryDefinition>(where => where.DirectoryTypeId == directoryTypeId).ToList();
      }

      return result;
    }
  }
```

On the form, I load the data into the grid through a BindingSource component. The child rows are added properly and the data is valid.

[image: Sample application]

**Here is the issue:** I'm able to add new `DirectoryTypePoco` but when try to add a `DirectoryDefinitionPoco`, in the code, the the `DirectoryDefinitionPoco`object that I get has a zero for it's parent object. In the above picture, the `Test5.dll234` is a `DirectoryTypePoco` with `DirectoryTypeId = 8` and all child under it are ok except the new one I create. What am I suppose to do to make sure I have Master-Child relation in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It seems that there are two thing I should have noticed in my design.

- The individual child Poco needs to know the parent Poco through a reference.
- The DevExpress Grid **has** methods that allow for retrieving the attached data to a parent row while in the child view' particular row.

The first part is straightforwards: add a new property in the child poco of parent poco type.

This however, in my case, doesn't solve my issue as when I visually add a new row on the grid, the default constructor is invoked and it takes no parameters and hence the parent poco reference will remain *NULL* and the Ids (numeric) will be defaulted to *0*

The second point helped fix my issue completely. I was able to conjure up an extension method for the XtraGrid's GridView as follows:

```
public static class DevExpressGridHelper
{
  public static IBasePoco GetPocoFromSelectedRow(this BaseView view)
  {
    return (IBasePoco)view.GetRow(((GridView)view).FocusedRowHandle);
  }

  public static IBasePoco GetParentPocoFromSelectedRow(this GridView view)
  {
    if (view.ParentView !=null)
    {
      // return (IBasePoco)(view.ParentView).GetRow(((GridView)(view.ParentView)).FocusedRowHandle);  
      return (IBasePoco)((GridView)view.ParentView).GetFocusedRow();
    }

    return null;

  }

}
```

And used it as follows:

```
private void GridMain_Level_1_RowUpdated(object sender, RowObjectEventArgs e)
{
  var view = sender as GridView;

  if (view == null)
  {
    return;
  }

  var pocoObject = e.Row as DirectoryDefinitionPoco;

  if (pocoObject == null)
  {
    return;
  }

  var parentPocoObject = view.GetParentPocoFromSelectedRow();

  if (parentPocoObject == null)
  {
    return;
  }

  if (view.IsNewItemRow(e.RowHandle))
  {
    Create(pocoObject, parentPocoObject);
  }
  else
  {
    Update(pocoObject);
  }
}
```